How to remove regen from a motor to prevent damaging the source?
I have a motor which controls a wheel, the wheel has no friction braking so I need to use regen to slow the motor down. The supply is 24V through a DCDC down from ~400V. As the DCDC is not bidirectional and the regen can be upto 4kW I need a way to protect the DCDC while still braking. I assume the best way for this is a braking resistor? If so, is this the best way I can implement something like this?

I appreciate any thoughts or help on this!
Thank you!

What does the inverter do? Will it conduct regen current back to the braking resistor? If not, why is the braking resistor at the inverter's input?

What Simon says. (Long ago memories stir :-) ) . How does the region energy transit the inverter.. more usual would be a three phase rectifier on the motor with a PWM modulated resistive load. More details please.

https://www.baldor.com/brands/baldor-reliance/products/ac-motors/clutches---brakes/clutch---brake-modules  might be a better solution but he is trying to inject DC across the windings after the 3 phase AC is removed

In all honestly I don't know much more information. My assumption is that the regen will go back to the braking resistor as it would be going in that direction to charge a would be battery if that was used instead of a DCDC.
My boundary diagram stops on the output of the 24V DCDC. The rest is on a 3rd party side. I am just trying to protect the DCDC whiltst allowing the units to brake. I am tempted to just say this is their solution to figure out.
